# What is the most efficient way to override an attribute in lots of my Moose based sub classes?

Tags: perl, moose

I am using [HTML::FormHandler](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::FormHandler). To use it one is supposed to subclass from it and then you can override some attributes such as `field_name_space` or `attribute_name_space`.

However, I now have lots of forms all extending `HTML::FormHandler` or its DBIC based variant [HTML::FormHandler::Model::DBIC](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::FormHandler::Model::DBIC) and therefore have these overidden attributes repeated many times.

I tried to put them in a role but get an error that `+attr` notation is not supported in Roles. Fair enough.

What is the best way of eliminating this repetition? I thought perhaps subclassing but then I would have to do it twice for `HTML::FormHandler` and `HTML::FormHandler::Model::DBIC`, plus I believe general thought was that subclassing is generally better achieved with Roles instead.

**Update:** I thought it would be a good idea to give an example. This is what I am currently doing - and it involves code repetition. As you can see one form uses a different parent class so I cannot create one parent class to put the attribute overrides in. I would have to create two - and that also adds redundancy.

```
package MyApp::Form::Foo;

# this form does not interface with DBIC
extends 'HTML::Formhandler';

has '+html_prefix'          => (default => 1); 
has '+field_traits'         => (default => sub { ['MyApp::Form::Trait::Field'] }); 
has '+field_name_space'     => (default => 'MyApp::Form::Field');
has '+widget_name_space'    => (default => sub { ['MyApp::Form::Widget'] }); 
has '+widget_wrapper'       => (default => 'None');

...

package MyApp::Form::Bar;

# this form uses a DBIC object
extends 'HTML::Formhandler::Model::DBIC';

has '+html_prefix'          => (default => 1); 
has '+field_traits'         => (default => sub { ['MyApp::Form::Trait::Field'] }); 
has '+field_name_space'     => (default => 'MyApp::Form::Field');
has '+widget_name_space'    => (default => sub { ['MyApp::Form::Widget'] }); 
has '+widget_wrapper'       => (default => 'None');

...

package MyApp::Form::Baz;

# this form also uses a DBIC object
extends 'HTML::Formhandler::Model::DBIC';

has '+html_prefix'          => (default => 1); 
has '+field_traits'         => (default => sub { ['MyApp::Form::Trait::Field'] }); 
has '+field_name_space'     => (default => 'MyApp::Form::Field');
has '+widget_name_space'    => (default => sub { ['MyApp::Form::Widget'] }); 
has '+widget_wrapper'       => (default => 'None');

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for `HTML::FormHandler::Model::DBIC` is actually in a Moose trait in order to help with this situation. You can inherit from your base class, and in your forms that use the DBIC model, you can do

```
with 'HTML::FormHandler::TraitFor::Model::DBIC';
```

Comment: would this be in any way less efficient?

Comment: No. If you look at the HTML::FormHandler::Model::DBIC package it includes the trait using 'with' also. So the 'with' is only being done in a different place. The only issue is that if a trait is included in the current package, an 'update_model' method might have to use a method modifier if you want to call the model's update_model method (which is done with next::method usually).

Comment: Great - I think this must be a feature added since I posted this question. Thank you so much for all your hard work on this module, Gerda! It's awesome.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, roles are composed into a class, they have nothing to do with subclassing. A subclass is a full class that extends a parent (or more than one, but in my experience multiple inheritance should be avoided if it can be). A role is a piece of behaviour, or a parial interface that can be applied to a class. The role then directly modifies the class. There's no new class created in general.

So inheritance and role composition are really two different things and two different kinds of design. Thus you can't simply exchange one for the other. Both have different design-implications.

My strategy with `HTML::FormHandler` has been to make a real subclass for each form that I require, and put the different behaviours of the form that I wanted to re-use into roles.

I'd think this question (how to implement the extensions you need in a clean and sane way) can't really be answered without knowing the actual design you're aiming for.

**Update:** I see what you mean and that's a tricky case. `HTML::FormHandler` is primarily targetted at extension by inheritance. So I think the best strategy would indeed be to have two subclasses, one for `HTML::FormHandler` and one for `HTML::FormHandler::Model::DBIC`. It seems teadious at first, but you might want to have different settings for them in the long run anyway. To avoid repeating the actual configuration (the default values) I'd try the following (this example is plain HFH, without DBIC):

```
package MyApp::Form;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

extends 'HTML::FormHandler';
with 'MyApp::Form::DefaultSettings';

# only using two fields as example
for my $field (qw( html_prefix field_traits )) {
    has "+$field", default => sub {
        my $self   = shift;
        my $init   = "_get_default_$field";
        my $method = $self->can($init)
          or die sprintf q{Class %s does not implement %s method}, ref($self), $init;
        return $self->$method;
    };
}

1;
```

Note that you'd need to make an attribute lazy if it requires the values of another attribute for its computation. The above base class would look for hooks to find the initialized values. You'd have to do this in both classes, but you could put the default subroutine generation into a function you import from a library. Since the above doesn't require direct manipulation of the attribute anymore to change the default values, you can put that stuff in a role I called `MyApp::Form::DefaultSettings` above:

```
package MyApp::Form::DefaultSettings;
use Moose::Role;
use namespace::autoclean;

sub _build_html_prefix  { 1 }
sub _build_field_traits { ['MyApp::Form::Trait::Field'] }

1;
```

This method will allow your roles to influence the default value construction. For example, you could have a role based on the one above that modifies the value with `around`.

There is also a very simple, but in my opinion kind-of ugly way: You could have a role provide a `BUILD` method that changes the values. This seems pretty straight-forward and easy at first, but it's trading extendability/flexibility with simplicity. It works simple, but also only works for very simple cases. Since the amount of forms in web applications is usually rather high, and the needs can be quite diverse, I'd recommend going with the more flexible solution.

Comment: Yup, I understand that. What I meant was I have managed to reduce my reliance on subclassing by using Roles and it has served me well. It does not help me here though. I have added an example so you can see my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Would this method, using multiple inheritance (I know I know, ugh), where you put your common default overrides in one class, and then your customized code in others?

```
package MyApp::Form;

use Moose;
extends 'HTML::Formhandler';

has '+html_prefix'          => (default => 1); 
has '+field_traits'         => (default => sub { ['MyApp::Form::Trait::Field'] }); 
has '+field_name_space'     => (default => 'MyApp::Form::Field');
has '+widget_name_space'    => (default => sub { ['MyApp::Form::Widget'] }); 
has '+widget_wrapper'       => (default => 'None');

package MyApp::Form::Model::DBIC;

use Moose;
extends 'MyApp::Form', 'HTML::Formhandler::Model::DBIC';

# ... your DBIC-specific code
```

Now you can descend from MyApp::Form or MyApp::Form::Model::DBIC as needed.

Comment: I'll have a think about it. Not sure if I can safely inherit from both HTML::FormHandler and HTML::Formhandler::Model::DBIC